# How to pass a variable in constructor using JPA at @Query in java?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here I have passed the Language enum variable in PostResponse's constructor also searched the web and casted the same as well. But it says

> ')', ',' or  expected, got '(' ***ERROR***

Error occured at cast part. Here is the code below. I am new to java and Jpa. Thanks in Advance.

```
@Query("select new PostResponse(mPost, cast(:language as LanguageCode)) from Post mPost")
    List<PostResponse> getLastPosts(@Param("language") LanguageCode language);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass PostResponse instance in your query. You can write your Spring Data JPA queries for Post entity like below:

```
// Spring Data query with field names 
List<Post> findByLanguageCode(LanguageCode languageCode);

// Or you can write your custom query 
@Query("select p from Post p where p.languageCode = :languageCode")
List<Post> findAll(@Param("languageCode") LanguageCode languageCode);
```

Comment: Yeah but I need the return of the jpql query to return in PostResponse type with further its modification in its constructor thats why I need to past it in the parameter.

Comment: @VijinKV you have to convert your JPA results to PostResponse in your service layer not in repository layer.